# RSpec Model Testing: Failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am teaching myself RSpec (v3.1.7). I have installed rspec with `rails g rspec:install` into an existing rails app - freshly created.

I created a model: `rails g rspec:model zombie`. Ran the migration and all went well.

In: app/models/zombie.rb:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true
end
```

In: app/spec/models/zombie_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Zombie, :type => :model do
  it 'is invalid without a name' do
    zombie = Zombie.new
    zombie.should_not be_valid
  end  
end
```

In terminal when I ran (in the app dir): `rspec spec/models` I get:

```
F

Failures:

1) Zombie is invalid without a name
 Failure/Error: zombie.should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `name' for #<Zombie id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
 # ./spec/models/zombie_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Im following a video tutorial and I followed the video (Testing with RSpec) down to the latter. I'm like losing weight on the 2nd chapter. Am I missing something? Is the video using an older version of rspec for their video tutorial?

In my migration file:

```
class CreateZombies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :zombies do |t|

      t.timestamps
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have created an `attr_accessor :name` and it works yes. But the video has no attr_accessor! I'm sooo lost!

Comment: Check these two links: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method adn http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations-in-different-environments

Answer (score 0):

Your model don't know what `name` is since you did not define the attribute in your migration:

```
class CreateZombies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :zombies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
     end
  end
end
```

Then run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then this should work fine:

```
z = Zombie.new(name: 'foo')
z.name
 => 'foo'
```

Comment: Nothing works. I did tried adding the table name before asking the question but same thing.

Comment: Well try harder because this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the name attribute. The following migration file will add name attribute to zombie model:

```
class AddNameToZombies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :zombies, :name, :string
  end
end
```

finally run the following commands:

```
rake db:migrate

rake db:test:prepare
```

and that's it